# how to create postgresql server on rhel7 linux vm in gcp

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am actually planning to have a PostgreSQL instance on rhel7 linux vm running on google cloud platform,

Can you let me know the process for the same.

One more query is it ok to install postgresql on vm rather than going for a cloud sql instance on gcp?

Thanks,
Moin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to the [PostgresSQL official downloads page for redhat](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/) and install the software.

You can get the RPMs there if you need to do an air-gapped installation.

You'll need to configure postgres later. See Posgres docs [Chapter 18. Server Setup and Operation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime.html).